# Brother HL printer seemingly installed, but not printing

Tags: printing, brother

I have a brother HL-L2340DW.

The "Printers" application shows it is installed.

However, "Print Test Page" is greyed-out.

Also, when I try printing a pdf nothing gets sent to the print queue.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I also own a printer in the HL series and experienced the same issues. I recommend you download the ppd file for your model from there and load it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Download the tool: http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006893/linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz

The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory, e.g. /home/UserName/Download

Open a terminal window:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step:

```
cd /home/UserName/Download
```

Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

```
gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1.gz
```

Get superuser authorization with the sudo command:

```
exec sudo -i
```

Run the tool:

```
cd /home/UserName/Download
bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 HL-L2340DW
```

The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.

When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",

```
For USB Users: Choose N(No)
For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI.
```

The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2700dw_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625

This link helped me, here are the instructions it lays out in case the link doesn't work in the future:

STEP 1 tells you to download the tool, but to avoid giving links that might not stand valid in the future, just google: "linux brother printer driver tool installer" and it should be provided by the brother printer website.

"Step1. Download the tool.(linux-brprinter-installer-..-.gz)

The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory. (The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.) e.g. /home/(LoginName)/Download

Step2. Open a terminal window.

Step3. Go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step. By using the cd command.

e.g. cd Downloads

Step4. Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

Command: gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-..-.gz

e.g. gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz

Step5. Get superuser authorization with the "su" command or "sudo su" command.

Step6. Run the tool:

Command: bash linux-brprinter-installer-..- Brother machine name e.g. bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 MFC-J880DW

Step7. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.

When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",

For USB Users: Choose N(No) For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI number.

The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete."

Comment: The link may break... How does the answer still stand valid, please?

Comment: May I suggest to add the steps mentioned in your link, or better the step you took to solve your problem?

Comment: I added another comment with the instructions. :)